# dynamic storage option in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to be able to set the paperclip storage option after model initialize, is this possible?

eg: User A will be using S3 storage, User B will be using file storage, etc

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible within Paperclip because the settings are done on a class level. You would need to switch the settings on the class on a per-user basis, and that code might be difficult to write.

Comment: Yes I've been trying for ages without any luck.. I'm sure there are use cases that would benefit from this approach... eg, in Basecamp's scenario, each account can setup to whether use Basecamp's storage or setting up a SFTP account..

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ryan Bigg's answer, you may benefit from [creating some middleware](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) for it?

You may also benefit from [this tutorial](http://tpy-blog.logdown.com/posts/168346-how-to-dynamically-assign-store-path-and-url-in-paperclip) or may consider [this delayed upload tutorial](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/asynchronous-s3/) (to perhaps send the image to the dynamic storage facility after upload)

Other than that, it's going to be a core-level Rails job